# Difference between values of different categories in Power BI matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to show the difference between two numbers. Same "value", but the different filter/dimension.

The value is "development costs" filtered for 2 different business plans categories.

Phrased as a question: The development cost for project A's initial business plan is 500,000 but in 2020 it was 600,000. What is the variance?

Example of matrix format: 
[image]

And this is my setup in Power BI on the Matrix table visualization
[image]
[image]

Bonus points if you could also show in a % change

I tried creating 2 filtered values, then a difference of those filtered values, but this is not practical for comparing many different values across different business plans. Choosing the filters should ideally automatically refresh the variance

Comment: How do you calculate variance with more than 2 plan columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a measure like the following:

```
Variance = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Cost]),'Table'[Business Plan]="Initial Business Plan")-CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Cost]),'Table'[Business Plan]="2020 Business Plan")
```

If you want it as a %:

```
Variance_perc = (CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Cost]),'Table'[Business Plan]="Initial Business Plan")-CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Cost]),'Table'[Business Plan]="2020 Business Plan"))/CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Cost]),'Table'[Business Plan]="Initial Business
```